# error "grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root"

Tags: grub2, root

I am running Ubuntu 16. I got this error every time I try to run the `update-grub` command.

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it:
in Ubuntu this command does not work:

```
su -i
```

instead, I used

```
sudo -i
```

After that I exported these paths:

```
export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

then

```
update-grub
```

Comment: you don't need to do all that

Comment: Well, I tried your suggestions and other answers but nothing work. This is the only thing works for me.

Comment: Your system is broken then :(

Comment: using the solution I posted, everything works fine ;)

Comment: Run with sudo update-grub.it will work...